# Eliminar una barra invertida dentro de una cadena en Python

Tags: python, string

Mi problema es el siguiente. Tengo unas cadenas con unas secuencias de escape incorrectas que quiero imprimir correctamente.

Por ejemplo, si tengo estas dos cadenas:

```
cadena1 = "Hola\\x20que\\x20tal"
cadena2 = "Hola\\040que\\040tal"
```

Al imprimirlas dan como salida:

```
Hola\x20que\x20tal 
Hola\040que\040tal
```

Mi intención es que queden:

```
"Hola\x20que\x20tal" 
"Hola\040que\040tal"
```

Para poder imprimirlas correctamente:

```
Hola que tal
```

He intentado sin éxito reemplazar "\\" por "\", de la siguiente manera:

```
print(cadena1.replace("\\\\", "\\"))
print(cadena2.replace("\\\\", "\\"))
```

Pero se imprimen mal:

```
Hola\x20que\x20tal
Hola\040que\040tal
```

¿Cómo podría solucionarlo?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Versión de Python? ¿Por dónde imprimes? ¿consola? ¿Jupyter notebook? ¿IDE?. Te pregunto, por que al menos en mi consola no consigo reproducir tu problema, los espacios se ven perfecto.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho es `Python 3.6.7 [GCC 8.2.0] on linux` El IDE utilizado es PyCharmCE, pero desde la consola, utilizando el intérprete sucede igual

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo que tienes es un literal de cadena UTF-8 (`str` en Python 3 usa dicha codificación) con secuencias de escape escapadas. El proceso para obtener lo que quieres  seria el siguiente:

```
cad = "Hola\\x20que\\040tal\\040est\\xc3\\xa1s" # Hola que tal estás

cad = (cad.encode("utf-8")           # b'Hola\\x20que\\040tal\\040est\\xc3\\xa1s'
          .decode("unicode-escape")  # 'Hola que tal est\xc3\xa1s'
          .encode("latin-1")         # b'Hola que tal est\xc3\xa1s
          .decode("utf-8")           # 'Hola que tal estás'
          )

print(cadena)
```

- Primero codificamos la cadena UTF-8. Con ello obtenemos una cadena de bytes:

  ```
  b'Hola\\x20que\\040tal\\040est\\xc3\\xa1s'
  ```
- A continuación decodificamos la cadena de bytes mediante `unicode-escape`, lo cual nos lleva a cabo el *"unescape"*, obteniendo una cadena (`str`) de la forma:

  ```
  'Hola que tal est\xc3\xa1s'
  ```

  Si no fuera por el carácter `á` que usa dos bytes en UTF-8 para codificarse, podríamos dejarlo aquí. El problema es que esto genera al imprimirlo:

  ```
  Hola que tal estÃ¡s
  ```

  Es decir, `\xc3` y `\xa1` son tratados como caracteres independientes, como si de una codificación de 8 bits se tratara (como Latin-1 - ISO/IEC 8859-1).
- Para solucionar lo anterior, volvemos a codificar pero usando ISO 8859-1  para preservar el orden de los bytes y por último codificamos usando UTF-8, codificación nativa usada por `str` en Python 3.

Comment: en python 2.7 me funciona solo colocando:
cadena1 = cadena1.decode('unicode-escape')

Comment: Gracias. Al final, haciendo caso a @ProsperoAguilar , lo he quedado `cadena1.encode().decode("unicode-escape")` No sé si así se podría ocasionar algún problema con otro tipo de caracteres, como por ejemplo tildes u otros caracteres especiales (voy a probarlo)

Comment: @Arg0s ten en cuenta que lo que obtienes así es una cadena Latin-1, no UTF-8. Prueba con  `cadena1 = "Hola\\040que\\040tal\\040est\\xc3\\xa1"` por ejemplo ("Hola que tal estás"). Si tu terminal usa Utf-8 como cabe esperar te imprimirá algo así `Hola que tal estÃ¡s` si no pasas la cadena a Utf-8.

Comment: @FJSevilla efectivamente.. se imprime tal y como dices. Y para lo que es, symlinks dentro la ruta `/dev/disk/` o directorios dentro de `/etc/fstab` (por ej., en mi caso `/dev/disk/'Data\x20Partition'`) , cuando Python los "capture" añadirá el backslash y, si contiene tildes, lo imprimirá mal. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Podrías usar `split` tal vez

```
cadena1 = "Hola\\x20que\\x20tal"
cadena2 = "Hola\\040que\\040tal"
print(cadena1.split('\\'))
print(cadena2.split('\\'))
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias, pero con ese resultado tendría el mismo problema.` " ".join(["Hola", "x020", "x20tal"]` me da como salida `'Hola x020que x20tal'`